# Using a variable as mapActions name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I try to use Vuex in a componnent (a datatable-like), embed in an other componnent (my page).

The DatatableComponnent is generic, and manage data from the main page, pass in props. I would like to pass a props string to the Datatable which contain the “link” for the mapActions, in order to manage the pagination.

I wrote that

For the main page

```
<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
  import datatable from '../../Outils/DataTable/datatable.vue'
  import datatableColumn from '../../Outils/DataTable/datatable-column.vue'
  import blocAddIntervenant from './blocAddIntervenant'

  export default {
    props: {
      type: {
        required: true,
        type: String
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        visibleBlocAdd: false
      }
    },
    computed: mapGetters({
      personnels: 'personnel/list/items',
      pagination: 'personnel/list/view',
      totalItems: 'personnel/list/totalItems'
    }),
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('personnel/list/getPersonnelType', this.type)
    },
    methods: {},
    components: {
      datatable,
      datatableColumn,
      blocAddIntervenant
    }
  }
</script>
```

For my DatatablCcomponnent I wrote this

```
<template>
   <div class="dataTables_paginate" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate" v-if="pagination">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="paginate_button page-item previous" :class="{'disabled' : !pagination['hydra:previous']}">
                <button data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0"
                        @click="getPage(pagination['hydra:previous'])"
                        :disabled="!pagination['hydra:previous']"
                        class="page-link">
                    Précédent
                </button>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button page-item" v-for="page in nbpages"
                :class="{'active' : pagecourante === page}">
                <a href="#" :data-dt-idx="page" :tabindex="page"
                   class="page-link">{{ page }}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="paginate_button page-item next" :class="{'disabled' : !pagination['hydra:next']}">
                <button
                        data-dt-idx="7"
                        tabindex="0"
                        @click="getPage(pagination['hydra:next'])"
                        :disabled="!pagination['hydra:next']"
                        class="page-link">
                    Suivant</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import headerSetting from './header-settings.vue'
    import {mapActions} from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: 'datatable',
        props: {
            source: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
            mapAction: '',
            totalItems: 0,
            pagination: {},
            actionBar: {
                default: false,
                type: Boolean
            },
            addButton: {
                default: false,
                type: Boolean
            }
        },
        data () {
            return {
                pagecourante: 3,
                columns: [],
                inputParams: [],
                inputParamsSearch: [],
                filter: null,
                sortingId: null,
                isShowAdd: false,
                isShowSearch: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addColumn (column) {
                this.columns.push(column)
            },
            ...mapActions({
                getPage: '"' + this.mapAction + '"'
            })
        },
        created () {
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I have an error : [vuex] unknown action type: "undefined"
I don’t understand why, because I have a value in mapAction. Maybe I don’t understand something in Vuex.

If I try this

```
getPage () {
    this.$store.dispatch('"' + this.mapAction + '"')
}
```

I have this error

vuex.esm.js?edaa:417 [vuex] unknown action type: “personnel/list/getPersonnelPagination”

But this action exists in personnel/list.js

```
const actions = {
  getPersonnelPagination ({commit}, page) {
    commit(loading(true))
    fetch(page)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        commit(loading(false))
        commit(success(data['hydra:member']))
        commit(view(data['hydra:view']))
      })
      .catch(e => {
        commit(loading(false))
        commit(error(e.message))
      })
  }
}
```

And if i try without the "

```
getPage () {
    this.$store.dispatch(this.mapAction)
}
```

I have an other error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘includes’ of undefined
at webpack_exports.a (fetch.js?ed24:18)
at Store.getPersonnelPagination (list.js?efd7:66)
at Array.wrappedActionHandler (vuex.esm.js?edaa:704)
at Store.dispatch (vuex.esm.js?edaa:426)
at Store.boundDispatch [as dispatch] (vuex.esm.js?edaa:332)
at VueComponent.getPage (402:207)
at Proxy.boundFn (vue.esm.js?65d7:188)
at click (datatable.vue?e373:379)
at invoker (vue.esm.js?65d7:1983)
at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?65d7:1781)
```

I don’t understand, for me, it’s just string, why I cannot pass a variable with string to mapAction or dispatch ?

Thanks for your help,
David

Comment: You definitely need to do the dispatch without the quotes. What is the value of `this.mapAction` when you call `getPage()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will not work because `this.mapAction` is not defined at the point that this code is run. This code is executed when the component is declared which is  before an instance of the component is even created, so `this` does not refer to the component. `this.mapAction` is a prop which can only exist within the scope of a component.

```
...mapActions({
    //this.mapAction does not exist when this code is executed.
    getPage: '"' + this.mapAction + '"'
})
```

I think you are on the right track, the following `getPage()` looks correct. The other implementation with the quotes will not work (unless your action names are surrounded by quotes, which I find unlikely). But the value of `mapAction` needs to be a string for the name of an action in the store. The action must exist in the store too. If it is null, undefined, or not an action in the store, you will get an error.

```
getPage () {
    this.$store.dispatch(this.mapAction)
}
```

It appears that it is actually calling your action in the store based on the stack trace with this line `at Store.getPersonnelPagination (list.js?efd7:66)`, but there is possibly an error in the action handler.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It works with your solution, and, I have a mistake in my action. I need to use a parameter, but, I didn't pass this argument in the dispatch.

No it works !

Many thanks
David